# Drop top row of dataframe and make the second row variable names

Tags: r, loops, paste

I have list **clean_data_2009** containing 12 monthly data frames named **wireless_YY_mmm** each, where YY represents year 2009 abbreviated as 09 and mmm abbreviates the calendar months.

I want to drop the first row in each of the 12 dataframes, and then convert the first row to variables name row.  The command below works, but I want to write a loop instead.

```
clean_data_2009$wireless_jan_09 <- clean_data_2009$wireless_jan_09[-1,] %>% row_to_names(row_number = 1)
```

I have written the loop command to print the text that R should accept to manipulate the data frames using *paste* command, but R tries to read the *paste* command and thus gives me an error.  I try to fix it with the get command, but still run into the error shown below -

```
month <- c("jan", "feb", "mar", "april", "may", "june", "july", "aug", "sep", "oct", "nov", "dec")
year <- c("09") # "2010", "2011"
list_dt <- c("clean_data_2009$wireless")
rows2del <- c("[-1, ]")

for (y in year) {
  for (m in month) {

    print(paste(y,m,sep = "_") )
    print(paste(list_dt,m,y,sep = "_"))
    print(paste(paste(list_dt,m,y,sep = "_"),rows2del, sep=""))
    

    get(paste(list_dt,m,y,sep = "_")) <- get(paste(paste(list_dt,m,y,sep = "_"),rows2del, sep="")) %>% row_to_names(row_number = 1) 
  }
}
```

Error:

```
[1] "09_jan"
[1] "clean_data_2009$wireless_jan_09"
[1] "clean_data_2009$wireless_jan_09[-1, ]"
Error in get(paste(paste(list_dt, m, y, sep = "_"), rows2del, sep = "")) : 
  object 'clean_data_2009$wireless_jan_09[-1, ]' not found
```

Answer (score 1):

This alternative approach might help. If you already have your frames in a list, you can just loop through them, and using indexing to drop the first row, and set the names in a single `setNames()` call for each frame

```
lapply(clean_data_2009, \(d) setNames(d[-1,],d[1,]))
```

Comment: It works.  Thanks @langtang  ```for (y in year) {    for (m in month) {    cleaner_data_2009<-lapply(clean_data_2009, \(d) setNames(d[-1:-2,],d[2,]))
     }  
}```